# Change Screen Background programmatically of a Visual Studio Debug .Net Console Terminal

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, logging

Is there a way to change this property of visual studio debugger console programmatically?

I launch a lot of azure functions and sometimes I get confused about which project is which...

I tried to change using the static class of 'Console' but changes don't apply.

[image: A image of a vs debug.net console showing the property of changing the]

Answer (score 0):

Use     Console.BackgroundColor  and    Console.ResetColor() between your projects;

```
  Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;

  Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
  Console.ReadLine();

  Console.ResetColor();
```

Sample:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;

public class CustomConsoleLogger : ILogger
{
    private readonly string _categoryName;
    int result = 0;
    public CustomConsoleLogger(string categoryName, int test)
    {
        result = test;
        _categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        if (result == 1)
        {
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.Now}] [{logLevel}] [{_categoryName}] {formatter(state, exception)}");
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
}

public class CustomConsoleLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
{
    int result = 0;
    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
    {
        return new CustomConsoleLogger(categoryName, result);
    }
    public CustomConsoleLoggerProvider(int test)
    {
        result = test;

    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
        {
            builder.AddProvider(new CustomConsoleLoggerProvider(1));// 1 enable background color
        });

        var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
        logger.LogInformation("This is a sample log message.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to change it per Azure Function, so I know if a console background is red I know exactly that is that Azure function, and I've tried what are you suggesting and Console.Clear() throws: "System.IO.IOException: 'The handle is invalid."

Comment: I have 4 .Net 8 Azure Function v4 Worker/Isloated/Out-of-proc projects in the same solution that use Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

Comment: The color problem is affect by  ILoggerProvider. You can [create custom custom-logging-provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-logging-provider) to control the background color.

Comment: I have tried that as well, seems that it does nothing to the Visual Studio Debugger Console Application. Can you provide a link with an example of how to do it properly?

Comment: May I Know if you have any chance to check the update?